# Connecting phone to computer makes Eclipse hang (worse after update to ICS)

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, mobile, ubuntu

When I connect my phone to my laptop in developer usb mode, Eclipse freezes up (goes shaded) and it seems must be doing something like downloading 10,000 log messages from my phone. (?)

This behavior has gotten much worse since updating to ICS from gingerbread.

And ideas? There must be some simple setting I'm not realizing.

Eclipse is getting paralyzed by (?) trying to read every irrelevant log message possible from my phone.  (Galaxy Note) (ubuntu 12)

Thanks

P.S. Eclipse will sometimes hang right after being started - so it's not always the phone's fault. But today it works fine - until I connect my phone.

Comment: Just came across this myself. Also using Galaxy Note N7000 and Ubuntu 12. Eclipse loads fine (as long as the device is not plugged in when I start it) and I can use it fine, but as soon as I plug in my device it hangs. Will update if I find a solution.

Comment: Tried a fresh Eclipse install. No luck so far.

Comment: Also happens with Galaxy Gio on 12.04, but not on Ideos u8150, so maybe a Samsung problem?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and this seems to have helped:

1. connect the phone
2. execute `adb logcat -c` in a terminal in adb's folder (usually platform-tools)
3. start eclipse

`logcat -c` clears the log.

Comment: Thanks this helped for me. I've also decreased the level of log messages from `verbose` to `info` in the phone.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I changed the log level in the LogCat terminal of Eclipse itself, not sure if that will be enough for the future (looks like it works to stop it from choking right now).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. In fact I don't know if the issue was caused by reading log messages... but the simptoms are same: each time I connected my Android device Eclipse immediately hanged forever.

I was running Eclipse Juno 64bit on 64bit Debian 7.0 (Wheezy).

I finnaly solved the problem by running 32bit Eclipse Juno (4.2.2) under 32bit Java 1.7.